# Vuejs 3.2 Dynamic Component KO

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I try to use dynamic component to update my section.
But, when i click on my sidebar ('nav'), it dont change.
route.params.current change, but component is not loaded.

```js
<template>
  <q-page class="container q-py-lg">
    <div class="q-pa-md row q-gutter-md">
      
      <nav class="col">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(link, i) in links" :key="i" :class="link.label === route.params.current ? 'active' : 'cursor-pointer'" @click="router.push({ name: 'settings', params: { current: link.label }})">
            <span><q-icon size="xs" class="icon q-mx-sm" :name="link.icon"></q-icon></span>
            <span>{{  t(link.label) }}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <section class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-9">
        <q-card flat class="bg-teal text-white">
          <q-card-section>
            <component :is="getComponent(route.params.current)"></component>
          </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
      </section>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import { useRoute, useRouter } from "vue-router";

const { t } = useI18n();
const route = useRoute();
const router = useRouter();

const getComponent = (name) => import(`./Settings/${name}.vue`);

const links = [
  { label: "account", icon: "person" },
  { label: "gameBehavior", icon: "sports_esports" }
];

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that a route exists with the exact name 'settings' and that props are enabled for this route ? `props: true,`

Comment: Sure, the route exist, and they are no props !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a watcher for the `route` and on the callback function you can assign your `dynamicComponent` by passing any component name. In my case, I am watching for `route.name` (you can use any, as it is a basic example).

But the trick here is to wait for the component to load as it is an asynchronous import. That's how you can get the component easily.

Also use `shallowRef` instead of `ref` when you define `dynamicComponent`. `shallowRef` will ensure that the component itself is not made reactive, only the reference to it.

> Learn more about DynamicComponents [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

```html
<template>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
      <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- Pass the dynamicComponent variable as component -->
  <component :is="dynamicComponent"></component>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router'
import { shallowRef, watch } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

const route = useRoute();

// Use shallowRef instead of ref when you define dynamicComponent.
// shallowRef will ensure that the component itself is not made reactive,
// only the reference to it.
const dynamicComponent = shallowRef<any>(null);

// Watch for the change in the route name in the router
// You can watch any property
watch(route, async () => {
  dynamicComponent.value = (await import(`./views/${route.name as string}View.vue`)).default;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, 
I slightly modified the code, not typescript, but javascript, not route name, but route params, ... 
And it's work !

Comment: Awesome @Shoooryuken. It was an awesome experience working on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Component :is="getComponent"></Component>
<script setup>
import {ref, defineAsyncComponent} from 'vue'
const name =ref(null)  // if you use it - define it
const getComponent =computed(()=> 
         defineAsyncComponent(()=>import(`./Settings/${name.value}.vue`)
</script>
```

Comment: I slightly modified the code, it lacks the import of computed and parentheses.

It does not work.
thanks anyway